# Create a loop that calls an API and retries 3 times if it errors

Tags: javascript, api, loops

So just like the title says im trying to create a javascript loop that calls an API, if there is data returned it sets the let variable and jumps out the loop but if it errors it retries 3 times. I did some googling and came up with the following but its not working and i cant understand why?

```
  let data
  const maxTries = 3

  for (let i = 0; i <= maxTries; i++) {
    try {
      data = await getJson(url, true)
      if (data) {
        return data
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      throw err
    }
  }
```

Comment: its not clear to me why 3 attempts in a asynchronous call?

Comment: with your loop, regardless there is data or not, you run the function anyways. apart from all, this is an async operation, so your code doesnt even wait for the response of getJson(). It is best you make some research about multiple async requests

Comment: @CMartins was just an idea i had, couldnt see anything on best practices to not do that

Comment: "It's not working" is not a sufficiently detailed description of what happened when you tried.  What were the actual results?  This will loop if `data` is falsey.  Otherwise it will return (if `data` is truthy) or throw (if there is an exception) or fall out of the loop (before making the `maxTries + 2`nd attempt -- note your off-by-one error:  `maxTries = 1` will try twice) and in that case presumably will return _undefined_.  So what, of all that, is "not working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var maxRetries  = 3
    async fetchAndRetryOnError(url, requestOption, maxRetries = 3) {
        let response = await fetch(url, requestOption);
        let retries = 0
        while (!response.ok && response.status != 400 && retries < maxRetries) {
            console.log(response.status);
            await sleep(1000 + 1000 * 2 ** retries)
            retries += 1
            response = await fetch(url, requestOption);
            console.log(`Retry nr. ${retries} result: ${response.ok}`)
        }
        return response
    }

    async send() {
        let url = `your url`;
        let requestOption = "" // header or body of req.
        return await this.fetchAndRetryOnError(url, requestOption);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`throw` will stop everything. You probably want to do `console.error` only.